# How to compare two strings, of different length to find identical substring

Tags: java, arrays, string

The problem is:
Client accounts are filed under a classification system using codes eg MA400. I need a method that will reset the original MA400 to an updated code such as MA400.4. If the new code has 5 characters to which the original is reset then the method returns true. Not the best wording but that is all I have right now.

It hasn't been specified if the characters need to be in the same order, eg.

```
    String str = "abc123";
    String newStr = "xyz123abc";
```

I am assuming they need to be in the same order. So the above strings would only have 3 like characters.

```
    char[]array = str.toCharArray();
    char[]array2 = newStr.toCharArray();
```

I am thinking now to use a `compareTo` method on the two arrays, but I am not sure how this would work exactly. Perhaps I could use a for loop to stop comparing after the final element in the shortest string but not entirely sure if I can do much with that.

I feel like I am going about this in the wrong way and there is a less complicated way to check for like characters in a string?

Comment: What do you really want?

Comment: Does the order matter or not? Depending on this the problem could be very, very hard.

Comment: Do `"AAAAB"` and `"ABBBB"` have 5 same chars or 2?

Comment: What I really want is for the method to return true if there are 5 chars the same. Honestly not sure about the order, for now I am assuming that the order does not matter. This is from an introductory Java course so I suspect it would be the easier option in regards to order being important or not.

Comment: Maybe we could have a look at the problem itself? For instance do the chars need to be consecutive? eg is "abcde" and "a-b-c-d-e" valid?

Comment: So client accounts are filed under a classification system eg MA400. I need a method that will reset the original MA400 to an updated code such as MA400.4. If the new code has 5 characters to which the original is reset then the method returns true. Not the best wording but that is all I have right now.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding, or is there some reason that you can't just use the .contains(String str) method? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_contains.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand something like this will work. Remember this will only count unique characters. Order does not matter

```
public static boolean matchingChar(final String st1, final String st2) {

        if(st1 == null || st2 == null || st1.length() < 5  || st2.length() < 5) {
            return false;
        } 

        //This is if you wish unique characters to be counted only
        //Otherwise you can use simple int count = 0
        HashSet<Character> found = new HashSet<Character>();

        //found.size() < 5 so the loop break as soon as the condition is met
        for(int i = 0; i < st1.length() && found.size() < 5; i++) {         
            if(st2.indexOf(st1.charAt(i)) != -1) {
                found.add(st1.charAt(i));
            }
        }

        return found.size() >= 5;
    }
```

Comment: So `found.size()` will be the number of characters that are different right? If so, and I need the number that are the same, it is possible for me to do something like                                                             `int equivCharacters = str1.length() - found.size`   ?

Comment: `count.add(classification.charAt(i));` this incorrect apparently, why? It says int cannot be dereferenced

Comment: found.size() are the number of characters that are same.

Comment: @Maitiu not sure which code you are talking about. I am not using count.add(classification.charAt(i));